# Bypassing google server using tor proxy is not possible

Tags: google, proxy

I am looking how to bypass pass proxy using tor and torctl, I looked on various steps and wrote this script in python.

After starting tor, ideally this should work

```
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "127.0.0.1:8118"} )
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
#urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.fr')
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google.co.in/trends/hottrends/hotItems?geo=IN&mob=0&hvsm=0"))
```

which again gives this message :

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 528, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

I have already started tor and enabled control port using

```
tor --controlport 9051
```

after using tor as  tor as a SOCKS proxy.

```
tor SOCKSPort 1080
```

python:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "127.0.0.1:1080"})
>>> opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
>>> urllib2.install_opener(opener)
>>> import json 
>>> data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google.co.in/trends/hottrends/hotItems?geo=IN&mob=0&hvsm=0"))
```

which again gives same error message.

Is there any way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tor creates a SOCKS proxy. You're using an HTTP proxy which is not the same proxy type. You'll need to configured urllib2 to use a SOCKS proxy instead. Alternatively, you could use Privoxy to host an HTTP proxy on port 1080 and then tunnels to the SOCKS proxy that Tor is running.

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you please give any helpful link for  how to configure url2 to use SOCKS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317849/how-can-i-use-a-socks-4-5-proxy-with-urllib2